# Manually inserting into frame sets scrollbar to not work tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar, frame

I have a code with scrollbar that works correctly, if the widgets are inserted onto the frame during automatically(during runtime?). But once I add widgets by pressing a button, it does not work. Take a look here:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")

def more():
    tk.Button(second_frame,text='MORE').pack()

main_section = tk.Frame(root,bg='white')
main_section.pack()

scroll_frame = tk.Frame(main_section,bg='white')
scroll_frame.grid(row=3,column=0)

# Create A Canvas
my_canvas = tk.Canvas(scroll_frame,bg='white',borderwidth=0)
my_canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)

# Add A Scrollbar To The Canvas
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(scroll_frame, orient='vertical', command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

# Configure The Canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

# Create ANOTHER Frame INSIDE the Canvas
second_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas,bg='white')

# Add that New frame To a Window In The Canvas
my_canvas.create_window(0,0, window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

tk.Button(second_frame,text='Click for more buttons',command=more).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here once you press the button and more buttons are created the scrollbar does not become active but if you give a loop in the main block, the scrollbar will get active. For example:

```
for a in range(30):
    tk.Button(second_frame,text=a).pack()
```

If your wondering why are there alot of frames, this is taken out of a bigger code to make a MCVE out. What am I doing here wrong? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event is never been fired:

```
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

The reason is fairly easy when you know that your function adds buttons to `second_frame` and thats why `second_frame` will be configured in *width* and *height*.

so you need this line after defining the second_frame:

```
second_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You only configure the `scrollregion` when the canvas changes size (or more specifically, when the `<Configure>` event is triggered on the canvas).

When you add buttons to the inner frame, that won't cause the canvas to change size. Instead, you need to either bind to the `<Configure>` event on the inner frame, or explicitly reconfigure the scrollregion after adding the button.

```
def more():
    tk.Button(second_frame,text='MORE').pack()
    my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: Yeaa, that was the problem. Thanks ! Sadly I can just accept one answer :(